# What to return when exiting early from a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

I have a homework assignment in which I need to compute the edit distance between two strings. I got the initial function to work but I've been having trouble with this part

> Now add the cutoff into the edit distance. This shouldn't change what result are produced, but will drastically speed up the performance.

Here's my original function:

```
static unsigned int compute_edit_distance(const char *const a,
                                      const char *const b)
{
    if (strcmp(a, b) == 0) return 0;
    if (a[0] == '\0') return strlen(b);
    if (b[0] == '\0') return strlen(a);

    unsigned int remove_from_a =
        compute_edit_distance(a + 1, b) + 1;
    unsigned int remove_from_b =
        compute_edit_distance(a, b + 1) + 1;

    unsigned int remove_from_both =
        compute_edit_distance(a + 1, b + 1);
    if (tolower(a[0]) != tolower(b[0])) ++remove_from_both;

    return get_min(get_min(remove_from_a, remove_from_b),
               remove_from_both);
}
```

I've tried a few things, but none of them work. My latest change is this

```
if (depth == MAX_EDIT_DISTANCE_DEPTH)
{
    size_t a_length = strlen(a);
    size_t b_length = strlen(b);
    size_t max_length = (a_length > b_length) ? a_length : b_length;
    return MAX_EDIT_DISTANCE_DEPTH + max_length;
}
```

with a new function signature

```
static unsigned int compute_edit_distance(const char *const a,
                                      const char *const b, unsigned int depth)
```

but that doesn't work either.

Can I get a hint on how to do this right? Thanks!

Comment: @user1416970 A case where you return early from a recursive function because you know that you won't get anything from recursing further.

Comment: This has to do something. Do you correctly pass 'depth' to the functions?

Comment: Is the original code given to you or you wrote it yourself? What does the cutoff supposed to do? (Are you trying to quit comparison if it is at a known depth?)

Comment: @MatinKh I wrote the original code. I'm trying to quit comparison if it's at a known depth.

Comment: @MatinKh When I say it doesn't work, I mean that the answer ends up incorrect when I use any of my cutoff implementations. Basically, I'm supposed to print out the strings with the least edit distance from another string in order. Without the cutoff, the correct string are printed. With the poorly implemented cutoff, the wrong strings are printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass in the "depth remaining" as a parameter. That is, the first call gets passed the cut-off depth, and all the recursive calls get passed a smaller number, which you determine by the type of edit made.

The fundamental idea is that in your first solution, the depth is calculated after the branch is explored recursively. That is, the calls are all made down the branch, then the numbers added together on the way back up the branch.

You can still do this to calculate the depth, but to prevent the branch from going too far, you pass in a running total of the editing budget you have already used in the calls on the way down the branch, or equivalently the editing budget that remains.

You'll need some trick to pass back a number from the failing branch to make sure the number will be rejected. For example return a number that you know will be too large, then check the result at the end. E.g., return MAX_DEPTH + 1, or similar.

Comment: My failed solution above does something similiar but instead of returning a constant the value depends on the size of the string. (I was thinking the sizes might affect the edit distance.) I tried changing it to a constant and it prints a different set of wrong values.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are reducing the depth budget, which is the critical part. The value you return shouldn't change much from the original solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "reducing the depth budget"? Is it what the depth parameter is in my recursive calls? I just add 1 to depth.

Comment: I tried the way you posted. It changes the values, but not to the right ones. I don't think the depth budget was the problem.

Comment: I think the depth thing is incompatible with my original algorithm. Not sure which one to change.